# getting the fields of objects from an arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi
I have an array list that has seven objects with type "Points"

my "Points" class has 2 fields (1) int x ,(2) int y.

how can I print this list with `System.out.println` ?
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do first is override the `toString()` method of your Point class:

**Be very careful that you use the exact signature I have provided below.  Otherwise, the `toString` will not work as expected.**

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
}
```

Then, you can just loop over all of the Points and print them:

```
for(Point p: pointList) {
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Alternatly, you can just call `System.out.println(pointList)` to print the entire list to one line.  This is usually less preferred than printing each element on its own line, because it is much easier to read the output if there is one element per line.

Comment: In my "point" I have overrided the ToString method. and in the other class ,I want to print them ,but I can not .this is my code:

Comment: public void getList(List list) {
       
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i).toString());
        }

Comment: it prints :Class.Point@c4bcdc
Class.Point@4b4333
Class.Point@128e20a

Comment: @user, the problem is with your casing of `toString()`.  You must match the exact method signature in my post.  You have an upper-case `T` in your method.

Comment: @user: it's `toString()`, not `ToString()`.  Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

You should override `Point`'s `toString` method:

```
public class Point {
    int x,y;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "X: " + x + ", Y: " + y; 
    }
}
```

Then just iterate & print:

```
for (Point p : points) {
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

`points` is the `ArrayList` instance containing your 7 `Point` class instances.

Comment: In my "point" I have overrided the ToString method. and in the other class ,I want to print them ,but I can not .this is my code:

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code you used to override `toString` method?

Comment: public String ToString(){
        return "X" +x+ "Y"+y;
    }

Comment: There you go. Java is case sensitive. If you want to override `toString` method you **must** use the exact same casing. Right now, you are using `ToString` (capital initial **T**). Using the `@Override` annotation is useful. Use it. It would have given you a compiler error if you tried to override a non-existant parent method.